# Programming LCD over Serial using Python, Linux

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, lcd

I've been sent the below code for controlling the backlight on my LCD device

```
Sample for set the brightness of iIO backlight.
Brightness : 00H (dark)
0AH (bright)
brightness = 0xA;// fully light
write(/dev/ttyS0,0x95,1);// send 95H command function.
write(/dev/ttyS0,brightness,1);// send the brightness we want.
Checksum = 0x95 + brightness;
checksum &= 0x7F; //We won‟t use bit 7.
write(/dev/ttyS0, checksum,1); // send checksum.
```

Below is my Python Code which I'm have problems with, the error I'm getting is

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &=: 'str' and 'str'
```

I'm guessing there is a problem converting the hexcode. Any help would be gratefully received

```
import serial
import struct
import time
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS1',baudrate=57600)
checksum = "x95" + "x00"
checksum &= "x0F"
ser.write("x95")
ser.write("x00")
ser.write(checksum)
```

Comment: checksum should be a calculated number not a string. `checksum = (0x95 + value) & 0x7f` where value is the integer value you use for the backlight and 0x95 is 149 in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the checksum as a 7 bit integer value. ie:

```
checksum = (0x95 + value) & 0x7f
```

then write the binary values to the serial port.

```
import struct
value = 0
checksum = (0x95 + value) & 0x7f
cmd = struct.pack("<BBB", 0x95, value, checksum)
ser.write(cmd)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm no longer getting the error but still cannot control the backlight.

Comment: The documentation at http://www.ibase.com.tw/2009/tc/Manuals/iIO_UserGuide_(rev.2).pdf is not very clear but it seems in the example C code in section 8 that you should read a response byte with its checksum and possibly retry until it works. See the backlight function in the sample code.